# Return a value with jQuery each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i'm new to javascript, and I would like to retrieve values from JSON and push it into an array so that I can parse again this array in another function, But I don't know how to return the array after pushing element inside it.

In the following script I can't display values in items

```
function gC(b,c,p) {

    $.getJSON('getmonths', 'b='+b+'&c='+c+'&p='+p, processJSON);    
}

function processJSON(data) {
      var retval = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {

          retval.push(val); 
          //alert(retval.pop());
      });
      return retval;
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
       var b = $("#b").val();
       var c = $("#c").val();
       var p = $("#p").val();

       var items = [];

       items = gC(b,c,p);
       var i = 0;

       $('td').each(function(index) {
          $(this).attr('bgcolor', items[i]);
          i++;
       }
```

How could I access the array ?

thank !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have the code inside the callback:

```
function processJSON(data) {
    var retval = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        retval.push(val); 
    });
    $('td').each(function(index) {
        if (index < retval.length)
            $(this).attr('bgcolor', retval[index]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't return from an AJAX call, you have it call a callback function when it's done.

```
function gC(b,c,p) {
    var retval = [];
    $.getJSON('getmonths', 'b='+b+'&c='+c+'&p='+p, processData);
}

function processData(data){
  var retval = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      retval.push(val); 
      //alert(retval.pop());
  });
  alert(retval);
}
```

`processData` would be called when the AJAX call is done.  This can't return a value to another function, so all your logic has to be inside this callback function.

UPDATE: You can also pass in a callback function to `gC` to be called when it's done.

```
function gC(b,c,p,f) {
    var retval = [];
    $.getJSON('getmonths', 'b='+b+'&c='+c+'&p='+p, function(d){
       if(typeof f == 'function'){
         f(d);
       }
    });
}
```

Then you call `gC` like so:

```
gC(b,c,p,function(data){
    var retval = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        retval.push(val); 
        //alert(retval.pop());
    });
    alert(retval);
});
```

UPDATE2: I saw the code you added to the question.  This needs to be done in the callback.

```
gC(b,c,p,function(data){
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       items.push(val);
    });
    $('td').each(function(index){  // You don't need a separate i variable
                                   // you can just use the index from the loop
      $(this).attr('bgcolor', items[index]);
   }
})
```

Comment: Of course you could add an extra parameter to gC so that you can pass in a callback function if you need to do different things with the array in different places.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem remains the same, how can I then return value from processData ? because once I have parsed the JSON object, I toggle class of computed elements of the page (by also parsing them) and I have to reparse the processData() result to set values on each toggled element

Comment: @Jerec: You need to alter your logic.  You cannot return anything.  You have to toggle the classes inside the callback function.

Comment: The problem is that, since this is an asycronous call, `alert(items);
` will execute before `$.getJSON` gets a chance to populate it, so items will be empty at that time. As Rocket suggests, you need to do your work in a callback, so that you are sure to have the data retrieved by the ajax call.